# troubles shooting because of internal HD

Tags: boot

I have an Acer Aspire v5 with Ubuntu on it, and it mostly won't start anymore. When I boot Ubuntu on Live CD, I can see the internal HD in the File Explorer but when attempting to mount it, I get this message :

```
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/ubuntu/Ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64: 
Command-line mount -t "iso9660" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500" "/dev/sda1" "/media/ubuntu/Ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64"'
exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/sda1 is write-protected, mounting read-only mount: /dev/sda1 is already mounted or /media/ubuntu/Ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64 busy
```

In emergency I tried to install Ubuntu on my external HD and on an USB, but they don't boot neither. Also, when booting from Live CD, I have 8 messages before booting that `ATA1 comreset error n°16`. Please help...

Comment: Your hard drive or motherboard is probably broken (hardware issue). Probably the only way to fix it would be to get a new hard drive for it.

Comment: i dont think its the hard drive for i can t either start other installations neither on external hd nor usb key... and if it s the motherboard, s**t ! lol